# Swift: Unlabeled 'break' is only allowed inside a loop or switch, a labeled break is required to exit an if or do

Tags: swift, for-loop

I am trying to break from 'if' condition within a for loop and getting this error. Below is the code:

```
var isPresent = false
arrayList.forEach { item in
  if item.contains("xyz") {
     isPresent = true
     break
   }
}
```

I am getting this errorL

> Unlabeled `break` is only allowed inside a loop or `switch`, a labeled `break` is required to exit an `if` or `do`"

Can I not use unlabeled break here?

Comment: `arrayList`? WHat is this, Java? :p

Comment: Lol... real variable name is different. This was just a sample. Thanks for the edit on my question though!

Comment: By the way, you could still use `for item in arrayList` which has a `break`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closures can only `return` out of their local scope, there's no non-local returns (like in Ruby or Kotlin). You can't `break` out of them like this.

You're using the wrong function anyway, so you can entirely sidestep the issue:

```
let isPresent = arrayList.contains(where: { $0.contains("xyz") })
```